# How to write Terraform module to create multiple folders in same google cloud storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage, terraform-provider-gcp

There is a need to create multiple folders in side the Google cloud storage bucket. I am aware that the bucket can be created but not sure how to create multiple folders in the same bucket.

I think below code for one folder in the bucket.

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "storage_bucket" {
  name          = "my-test-bucket"
  location      = "us-east4"

  project       = "my-project"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "my_folder" {
  name          = "fold/"
  bucket        = "${google_storage_bucket.storage_bucket.name}"
}
```

Can anyone please let me how to do it for multiple folders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated to add content from raj S' answer.

---

You could use a set of strings and `for_each`. Something like below:

```
variable "folders" {
  type    = set(string)
  default = []
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "storage_bucket" {
  name     = "my-test-bucket"
  location = "us-east4"
  project  = "my-project"
}


resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "folder" {
  for_each = var.folders

  name    = each.key
  bucket  = google_storage_bucket.storage_bucket.name
  content = "folder_content"
}
```

Then an example input:

```
folders = [
  "fold/",
  "dir/",
  ...
]
```

That would dynamically create the `fold` and `dir` folders in the bucket from the input.

If you don't need to make the list of folders dynamic (i.e. hardcode them instead of variable inputs), you can also use locals instead of variables. Something like:

```
locals {
  folders = toset([
    "fold/",
    "dir/",
    ...
  ])
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "storage_bucket" {
  name     = "my-test-bucket"
  location = "us-east4"
  project  = "my-project"
}


resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "folder" {
  for_each = local.folders

  name    = each.key
  bucket  = google_storage_bucket.storage_bucket.name
  content = "folder_content"
}
```

Comment: Hi clarj, Thanks for your prompt response. A small clarification, where do I need to supply fold, and dir? should it be like default = ["fold/", "dir/"] at a variables.tf file ?

Comment: You can provide it any way you want, as you say you can use defaults in a variables.tf file, or pass them with a vars.tfvars file, or if you are creating a module, pass them directly to the module inputs. Really just depends on your scenario. If you don't need to make them dynamic (i.e. defined as variables), you can also use locals. I'll amend answer.

Comment: OK, we can define in variables.tf or locally. In these cases, do we need to keep folders in outputs.tf file?

Comment: with above code, I am getting an error either "content" or "source" must be specified. can you please let me know do we need to specify an empty source or content and how?

Answer (score 1):

to avoid error "content" or "source" must be specified, below code can be used.

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "folder" {
  for_each = local.folders

  name   = each.key
  content = "folder_content"
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.storage_bucket.name
}
```

It is the syntax as per terraform "google_storage_bucket_object". The empty folders will be created in the given bucket.

Answer (score 0):

The true answer is: "folder doesn't exist".

And you can check that, use gsutil on your folder

```
gsutil ls -la gs://<bucket>/fake-folder/
         0  2022-03-17T19:32:39Z  gs://<bucket>/fake-folder/#1647545559507877  metageneration=1
```

You can see that you have 1 file, of size 0, and with no character in the name. But you have an object generation (the #XXXXXX value).

---

Therefore, creating folder on Cloud Storage is simply a human representation, not a technical feature. All the files are stored at the root directory (the bucket) and the file name is the full path of the file, the "folder" included. By convention the `/` is a folder separator for human, but it's technicaly false.

The immediate consequence is that you can create any files in any folders event if the folders doesn't exist. Because the folder doesn't exist!!